# Java Reflection Question about String... parameter for method

Tags: java, reflection, code-injection

```
public static Client initClient(boolean paramBoolean, String... paramVarArgs) {
```

How would I reflect this method? I tried the follow -

```
final Method runClientMethod = clientClass.getMethod("initClient", Boolean.class, String.class);
```

```
final Method runClientMethod = clientClass.getMethod("initClient", Boolean.class, String[].class);
```

I am not sure how to properly declare `String... paramVarArgs` in reflection.  If your `getMethod` isn't identical, the method cannot be found.. my above attempt throws a MethodNotFound exception

Comment: What happens when you use a boolean.class param type? (lowercase letter)

Comment: Thanks! That worked, I'm an idiot.

Comment: varadic parameters (`T...`) are just syntactic sugar for a tailing parameter of an array of that (`T[]`). (ok, there is the `ACC_VARARGS` flag in the bytecode)